# Polymorphic array isn't working

Tags: java

```
package finalpaperpractice;
public class PolymorphicTest {
    public void function(){
        System.out.println("1");
    }
    public static void main (String [] args){
        Object obj [] = {new PolymorphicTest(), new A(), new B()};
        for (int i = 0; i < 3; i ++){
            obj[i].function(); // error on this line
        }
    }
}
class A{
    public void function(){
        System.out.println("2");
    }
}
class B{
    public void function(){
        System.out.println("3");
    }
}
```

I don't know why `obj[i]` isn't able to find `function()`.
I have written a code which overrides `toString()` which works perfectly but this code which doesn't override.

Comment: And what is the error message? Can you add it to the question?

Answer (score 2):

Because `obj` is `Object` type and `Object` class doesn't have `function` method declared.

You can either create an interface with `function` method and implement this interface in all classes wherever you want `function` method.

Then,

```
Object obj
```

should be change to

```
<Your Interface> obj
```

Comment: Then what is the solution to call `function()`

Comment: solution will differ depending on your requirement.

Comment: What is the solution in my case

Comment: As I mentioned, that depends on your application design. Anyway, one of the solution I have mentioned.

Comment: Thanks a lot, you gave a direction. 
The `function()` can be accessed by using either `Interface` or by using `extends`